# Identifying something on the screen

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, automation, automated-tests

I'm curious as to how the CodedUI Test functionality in Visual Studio works.

I can see how it can identify keypresses and what's typed by querying the keyboard state, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how (i.e. code-wise) it identifies what button was clicked, where that button is located, and how to track it if between the recording and test runs the button has moved or happens to be scrolled off the screen. I'm mainly interested in items which are foreign to me (i.e. I don't have access to the source code and/or it's running on a different process from my programs process).

Comment: Are you trying to replicate the functionality of CodeUI Test?